# Comparar url atual com href

Tags: jquery

O meu cenário é o seguinte, eu tenho 3 links e preciso identificar qual deles é o mesmo que a **url** atual.

```
<a href="meulink">Menu 1</a>
<a href="meulink2">Menu 2</a>
<a href="meulink3">Menu 3</a>
```

A maneira que utilizei para comparar se a url é a mesma do href foi essa:

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(url===href){
    console.log('works');
  }
});
```

Porém não funciona, cheguei a fazer um teste jogando o valor exato na variavel **url** e dá certo. Queria saber se eu devo utilizar o `window.location.href` mesmo ou ele dá algum problema na hora da comparação.

Esse valor do href é só um exemplo, estou tentando comparar os valores completos, por isso o uso do `window.location.href`

```
    <a href="http://localhost/teste/index.html">Menu 1</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/teste/naoindex.html">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/teste/tambemnaoindex.html">Menu 3</a>
```

Toda vez que eu estiver na página `http://localhost/teste/index.html` eu preciso adicionar uma classe ao `a` correto.

Uma outra alternativa que tentei foi o seletor `$(".nav a[href*='/sobre']").css('color','red');`, só que no lugar do 'sobre' tentei colocar a variável url, porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
$('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (url === href){
    console.log('works');
  }
});
```

`var url = window.location.href;` -- pega a url toda.

Então você utilizando `===` significa que os dados valores precisam ser exatamente iguais.

`var url = window.location.pathname;` -- pega só o que vem depois do host.

Exemplo: `www.seusite.com.br/teste.html`, utilizando o `window.location.pathname` ele vai retornar só `teste.html`

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Bruno, vc poderia explicar um pouco mais sua resposta?

Comment: var url = window.location.href; -- pega a url toda, então você utilizando === significa que os dados valores precisam ser exatamente iguais. Já o var url = window.location.pathname; -- pega só o que vem depois do host. Exemplo: www.seusite.com.br/teste.html, utilizando o pathname ele vai retornar só teste.html

Comment: Bruno, clica no botão editar, e coloca a explicação na resposta :)

Comment: Feito! Funcionou?

Comment: @Bruno, no meu caso eu preciso que a url seja exatamente igual a href, por isso estou usando o window.location.url

Comment: ficou melhor Bruno +1